# Today and Nerby scopes have disapeared

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, scopes

Turned my bq Aquaris 4.5 ubuntu edition phone on this morning and the "Today" and "Nerby" scopes have disappeared. Apps,News,Video and Photos are still working.

Any ideas? I have rebooted the phone but has not made any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not run any update or anything the only explanation I could think of is that you accidentally clicked on the star in the upper-right corner of those scopes and made them "disappear".

In order to re-enable just pull the menu from the bottom to **Manage** your scopes. You will find all scopes you currently use (**Home**) as well as all scopes installed (**Also installed**).
Scroll down to find the two scopes you are looking for and click on the star next to them.